# Center window and consider taskbar

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, position

I'm struggling around with an weird issue. I can't perfectly center my window because of the windows taskbar and I'm having a margin at the top of the screen with the exact same height as taskbar.

My application resolution size is: `1920` x `1017`, my screen size: `1920` x `1080`.

I have used the following to center my window:

```
CMSWindow::SetCenterPosition();
```

as well as:

```
int width = 1920;
int height = 1017;
int cx = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) /2 - width / 2;
int cy = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) /2 - height / 2;

SetPosition(cx, cy);
```

This is how it looks like - screen top margin:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpUiP.png)

How can I perfectly center the window considering the taskbar height/width?

Comment: You are probably looking for `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is this for getting the taskbar height?

Comment: It gets you the "work area" of the monitor - the area sans the toolbar and other app bars (if you have any; these are uncommon). It appears that you want to center your window within the work area.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have tested it but it doesn't work as expected, returns 40px of height for the taskbar, while taskbar has 35px so there is still a tiny margin.